# Class (not instance) constructor

Tags: python

Basically I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class A:
    some_field = None # that is the field which should have 123 value

    # what needs to be here?

class B(A(123)):
    pass

class C(A(456)):
    pass
```

I want one base class `A`. And I want children `B` and `C` to be able to pass arguments to it like that `A(123)`.

And for example if I do `B.some_field` I should get `123`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `B` and `C` like this:

```
class B(A):
    some_field = 123

class C(A):
    some_field = 123
```

then:

```
In [147]: B.some_field
Out[147]: 123
```

---

By the way, `A(123)` would pass 123 to `A.__init__`. It would not set `some_field`.

Also, in a class definition,

```
class B(...)
```

The stuff in parentheses must be a class or a comma-separated list of classes (or, in Python3, `metaclass=SomeMetaClass`). It can not be an instance of a class. So

```
class B(A(123))
```

is a definite no-no.

---

In response to the comment: You could use the `A.__new__` method to return a class:

```
class A(object):
    some_field = None 
    def __new__(cls, val):
        cls.some_field = val
        return cls

class B(A(123)): pass
```

then

```
In [161]: B.some_field
Out[161]: 123
```

But this is a non-standard use of `__new__` since usually it is used to return an instance of `A`. When it does not return an instance of `A`, then [`A.__init__` is not called](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Instead of using a `class A` it would be more understandable to use a class factory:

```
class B(make_class(123)): ...
```

as you mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: I understand that the stuff in parentheses must be a class, but I can do `def A(some_field): return make_class(SomeBase, some_field)` and then `class B(A(123))` would be perfectly valid. I just need some syntactic sugar. Wondered if I somehow could use a class instead of a method.

Answer (score 3):

unutbu's answer is correct.  I'd just like to point out that you can even do this stuff dynamically...

```
def make_class(base, value):
    class NewClass(base):
        some_field = value
    return NewClass

class A(object):
    some_field = None

B = make_class(A, 123)
C = make_class(A, 456)
```

And actually, this one is important enough that python actually has a *builtin* to do it:

```
class A(object):
    some_field = None

B = type('B', (A,), {'some_field': 123})
```

`type` takes 3 arguments -- The name of the class, a tuple of the base classes and a dictionary of class attributes.